# Working with multiple .nc4 files in Python with netNCDF4

Tags: python

I need to work with multiple .nc4 files with ascending times downloaded from NASA (three in the following example). I have tried to write the files into a simple list (here) (and also into numpy files -- not here), and read from these files serially with MFDataset from netCDF4 in a 'for' statement. I get an error that MFDataset doesn't exist.  (I also tried to simply read from the list serially with 'Dataset' in a 'for' statement, and got a message that the list file does not exist.) ??? Here is a subset of the file:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import glob
import netCDF4
wind00 = glob.glob('Merra/*')
print(wind00)
print()
for s in range(3):
    winddata = MFDataset('wind00[s]')
    print(winddata.dimensions.keys())
    print(winddata.variables.keys())
    print()
```

---

Many thanks

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `winddata = MFDataset('wind00{}'.format(s))`? `'wind00[s]'` is a string literal - the `s` in your `for` loop has nothing to do with the `"s"` in the string.

Comment: Thank you, roganjosh!   But I still get an error message "name 'MFDataset" is not defined"